# C# WPF ScrollBar no se muestra en DataGrid dentro de un GridCell

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola tengo un problema al meter un Datagrid dentro de un gridcell si le pongo altura en automático no me muestra el scrol.

Esta es mi tabla

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Y esta es mi tabla

```
<DataGrid  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.RowSpan="6"
                                           Height="auto" FontSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DG_Transaction}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                                           IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="DG_Transactions"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  CanUserSortColumns="False" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Lot}" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Lote" />
                                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                                </DataGrid>
```

y asi se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se le pongo una altura fija si se muestra pero si hacen grande la pantalla no llena el espacio faltaste

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que la fila donde está el grid tiene **auto** de height,. Prueba a ponerle * o 1.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Nop sigue igual, se me paso comentar que el grid esta dentro de un tabitem